# C# Passing objects between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, object

So I have two forms. LibraryBookDialog.cs and MainForm.cs. I'm trying to pass an object from LibraryBookDialog.cs to Mainform.cs. Problem is, I get this error when I try to do so...

```
object reference not set to an instance of the object
```

Here are my two forms...

LibraryBookDialog.cs:

```
private LibraryBook book;

public LibraryBook Book
{
    get { return book;}
    set { book = value;} 
}

private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validateData())
        {
            try
            {
                Book.Title = textBoxTitle.Text; 
                Book.Author = textBoxAuthor.Text;
                Book.CopyrightYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCopyrightYear.Text);
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "There was an error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

and MainForm.cs

```
private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LibraryBookDialogue dlg = new LibraryBookDialogue();
        dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (dlg.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBoxLibraryBooks.Items.Add(dlg.Book);
        }
        dlg.Dispose();
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: **Where** do you get the error? Did you use the debugger?

Comment: It happens after I click ok on the form, the catch {} is to see it. The JIT compiler tells me this.

Comment: Where do you set the value to `Book`? With the code you showed it seems you are trying to set the properties of a object that is null, you didn't set a value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never put a `LibraryBook` instance into the `Book` property.

Comment: How would I remedy this? (I'm new to windows forms)

Comment: Nevermind. I see I needed to initialize the LibraryBook object.

Answer (score 2):

```
private LibraryBook book = new LibraryBook();
```

or

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validateData())
    {
        try
        {
            // Create book instance and assign properties
            Book = new LibraryBook()
            {
                Title = textBoxTitle.Text,
                Author = textBoxAuthor.Text,
                CopyrightYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxCopyrightYear.Text)
            };
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "There was an error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `Book` property. It's never set to a value, so it will be `null` when you go to use it.

You could do something like this.

```
public LibraryBook Book
{
    get 
    { 
        if (book == null)
        {
            book = new LibraryBook();
        }
        return book;
    }
    set { book = value;} 
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and it seems to solve the problem, but now when I see the listBox, it shows up as an element (I can click it), but it is just a blank string (something wrong with the toString()? Or is it because the object was not created?). Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: `listBoxLibraryBooks` most likely doesn't know how to parse your `LibraryBook` objects, so you'll need to set the properties on `listBoxLibraryBooks` like: `listBoxLibraryBooks.ValueMember = LibraryBook.ID` (what the value is, eg: ID) and `listBoxLibraryBooks.DisplayMember = LibraryBook.Title` (what shows up on the GUI). View these pages for more information: [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) and [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)

Comment: I wish people would comment on a downvote. Lazy initialization might not be the best here (don't know your situation) but I'd confidently recommend it over re-initializing on each button click.